# How to add graphics options to an already produced plot having manipulator?

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I am new to *Mathematica* and stuck with one problem i.e.

How can I add a graphics option to an already made plot which a manipulator to control itself.

```
s = Manipulate[
   PopupWindow[
    Graphics[
     DiscretePlot[Sin[a t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize -> Full, 
      ImageSize->Scaled[1], AspectRatio -> .2]], {a}], 
   OpenerView[{"Vertical", Control[{{a, 1, "Manipulator"}, 1, 30}]}], 
   ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I want to add a plot `Label` by calling the already produced plot `s` because  I don't want the duplication of code again as I have to use 4  more different plots in a popupmenu. For example, when I select `s` from then popupmenu then it should give the output `t`

```
t = Show[s, PlotLabel -> "Popup Window Plot"]
```

but this is showing error `Show::gtype: Manipulate is not a type of graphics.`

Is there any way to sort out this problem?

**Note:** The MathGroup version of the same question is found [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/zxqQYNuus7o/discussion).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  In future question, you can use the formatting controls in the post editor (the `{}` icon, etc.) to make your post readable.  I fixed up the formatting now (you can click the edit link under the post to see how I did it).  I also removed the superfluous `]` character from the end of the first code block.

Comment: I can't test now, but would the following work? `t = s /. g_Graphics->Show[g, PlotLabel -> "Popup Window Plot"]`

Comment: There is an unnecessary `Graphics` wrapper in the code. Though it turns out to be very useful in the sense that one does not have to write a replacement (a la @celtschk) that lists all possible plot types.

Comment: [When you cross-post to MathGroup, please link the questions/answers together.] (I edited your post to include the link.) (http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/368/12)  If you get a good answer there, please come back here and summarize it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe as an alternative you could define `s` as a function, e.g.

```
s[opt : OptionsPattern[Plot]] := 
 Manipulate[PopupWindow[
   DiscretePlot[Sin[a t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6},
    opt,
    ExtentSize -> Full, ImageSize -> Scaled[1], AspectRatio -> .2], {a}], 
  OpenerView[{"Vertical", Control[{{a, 1, "Manipulator"}, 1, 30}]}], 
  ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

then for example `s[]` would give you the original `Manipulate` and `s[PlotLabel -> "Popup Window Plot"]` would add a label to the plot inside the `Manipulate`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
MapAt[Show[#, PlotLabel -> "Popup Window Plot"] &, s, {1, 1}]
```

The part specification `{1, 1}` should point to your `Graphics` object.

To affect *any* `Graphics` in `s` use as suggested by celtschk:

```
s /. g_Graphics -> Show[g, PlotLabel -> "Popup Window Plot"]
```

Comment: I think you need to use `SetDelayed` in the latter example to replace `g`, otherwise it drops an error.