# How to repeat a plot with different options

Tags: plotting

I'd like to have first a function plot and then the same plot repeated inside a `Manipulate`, with additional things (like tangent planes etc.).  I can do

```
plot=Plot3D[<whatever>]
```

and then

```
Manipulate[Show[plot,<whatever>],...]
```

but there is one problem.  I'd like to have the *second* plot semi-opaque, so that things are more visible.

My question is either (1) how to achieve this using my approach with `plot=Plot3D[...]`, or (2) is there any better approach?

I've seen [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6121/how-to-add-graphics-options-to-an-already-produced-plot-having-manipulator), but the first answer seemed too complicated (am I wrong?) and the second one didn't work for me...

Answer (score 2):

```
plot[opt : OptionsPattern[Plot]] := Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Bottom, opt];
plot[]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  plot[FillingStyle -> {Opacity[0.1]}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[.3]]],
  Plot[ a x, {x, 0, 6}]], 
{a, 0.1, 1/6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]