# Edit plot after creation

Tags: plotting, manipulate, options

I try to find a way to manipulate a plot I created before.

(for full code take the fuction

```
x[t_]:=Sin[2t]
```

)

Let's say I have a plot:

```
plot1 = Plot[x[t], {t, 0, 10},
   PlotStyle -> Purple,
   ImagePadding -> 55,
   Frame -> {True, True, True, False},
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Purple, Automatic, Automatic},
   FrameLabel -> {None, "Signal", None, None},
   LabelStyle -> {16},
   ImageSize -> 600
   ];
```

And later I want to use the same plot with a point on the line.
The complete code would be:

```
plot1 = Plot[x[t], {t, 0, 10},
   PlotStyle -> Purple,
   ImagePadding -> 55,
   Frame -> {True, True, True, False},
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Purple, Automatic, Automatic},
   FrameLabel -> {None, "Signal", None, None},
   LabelStyle -> {16},
   ImageSize -> 600,
   Epilog -> {Directive[{Purple}],PointSize -> Large,Point[{2,
   x[2]}]}
   ];
```

But is there another way? Something like

```
SetOptions[plot1,Epilog -> {Directive[{Purple}], PointSize -> Large, 
  Point[{2, x[2]}]}]
```

And what if I want to use this plot the second time in a Manipulate[] environment?

```
Manipulate[plot1,{dt,0,10}]
```

Till now I couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: Try `Show`, if I get it right.

Comment: @Kuba That's it! Does everything I need ... for now

Comment: @Kuba What if I want to change the PlotStyle? Let's say from Purple to Red?

Comment: Then you have to do something like [17250](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17250/5478)

Comment: I think the original question is arguably "easily found in the documentation" and the extended question is addressed in [Is it possible to change the color of plot in Show?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17250) (as Kuba already linked).  Either way I favor closing this question.

Comment: Also see: [(14556)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14556),
[(32845)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32845)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My question was not realy about the specific changes made in the linked topics. More like "is there a way to change/add plot options afterwards". But with all these answers here I got an idea of how to handle my problems. So of course it would be ok to close this question.

Comment: The question has already been closed by the vote of other community members.  Here are more related questions for you to examine: [(6121)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6121), 
[(11261)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11261), 
[(38971)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38971).  Also perhaps of interest: [(3247)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3247), [(22697)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22697), 
[(38827)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38827)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[plot1, 
  Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Purple, Point[{a, Sin[2 a]}]}]], {a, 0, 
  10}]
```

some thing else may be helpful.

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
 Show[plot1, 
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], 
    Point[Dynamic[{First[pt], Sin[2 First[pt]]}]]}]], 
 Appearance -> None]
```

Comment: same answer as Kuba, but it's not only about the Point[], it's about PlotOptions in general.

Comment: I don't think there is option in Plot in which you edit an existing plot or picture. the only option is to treat the created plot as image and use other functions that work with images.

Answer (score 0):

```
plot1 = Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Purple, 
   ImagePadding -> 55, Frame -> {True, True, True, False}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Purple, Automatic, Automatic}, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, "Signal", None, None}, LabelStyle -> {16}, 
   ImageSize -> 600];

Manipulate[Graphics[{
                    plot1[[1]] /. Purple -> Directive[{Thick, Red}], 
                    PointSize -> Large, Point[{a, Sin[a]}]
                    }, 
       Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}}, 
       LabelStyle -> Directive[Italic, Large], AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
       plot1[[2]]], {a, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

There is also `` Experimental`Explore[] `` (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7450/125) by rm-rf) if you have Version 8 (but it does not work with Version 9.0.1.0, Windows 8)