# Edit DensityPlot after creation

Tags: plotting, options

My question is similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51414/edit-plot-after-creation?lq=1) question, of which I have found the solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17250/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-plot-in-show). The solution enables me to edit a Plot after it has been drawn, so that Mathematica doesn't have to compute everything it needs for the plot again.

Now I have the same question, but for a [`DensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html), or actually a [`ListDensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html) (I'm assuming here that the answers to this question will be similar for both commands, correct me if I'm wrong). In particular, I have some `ListDensityPlots` of which I want to change the frame labels. How can I do this?

To give a specific example, given the plot

```
p = ListDensityPlot[Table[{x, y, x^2 - y^2}, {x, -1, 1, 1/100}, {y, -1, 1, 1/100}] 
// Flatten[#, 1] &, FrameLabel-> {x, y}],
```

can I add the option `RotateLabel -> False` afterwards using `Show`?

Answer (score 4):

```
p1 =
 ListDensityPlot[
  Table[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1, 1/10.}, {y, -1, 1, 1/10.}],
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
  PlotLabel -> Style["Rotated", 14, Bold],
  RotateLabel -> True];

p2 =
 Show[p1,
  RotateLabel -> False,
  PlotLabel -> Style["Not rotated", 14, Bold]];

Grid[{{p1, p2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, strange that I didn't realize that this actually worked... So the FrameLabel soft options are options I can easily change with Show. Do you know how to change other "non-soft" options of the plot which, like the ColorFunction?

Comment: With `Show` you can only change the options listed with `Options[Graphics]`. To change the `ColorFunction` you have to make another plot.